# How to calculate the t-test columnwise, by fixing my own true value of the mean

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, sapply

I'm trying to comput t-test columunwise and fixe the true value of mean (`mu`) to 0.9. The follwing is my code chunk.

**data set**

```
vec1 <- c(.5,.1, .03, .2, .09, .02,.3,.4,.6,.8)
vec2 <- c(5, 4,3, 8, 3, 1, 4,1, 10, 5)
vec3 <- round(rnorm(10), digits = 2)
tab <- cbind(vec1, vec2, vec3)
tab
```

**code**

I used the following `apply` function

```
k <- apply(tab, 2, t.test)
k
```

But this do not allow to fixe the `mu`. It computs the *t-test* with the default `mu`.
Then, I tried to create a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(tab)) {
  h=list()
  h[[i]]=t.test(tab[,i], mu=0.9)
print(h)
}
```

I got a list of length 3 as I want. But
something strange is happening in the output.

> h
> [[1]]

```
One Sample t-test
```

data:  tab[, i]
t = -7.0941, df = 9, p-value = 5.703e-05
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.9
95 percent confidence interval:
0.1139489 0.4940511
sample estimates:
mean of x
0.304

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]

```
One Sample t-test
```

data:  tab[, i]
t = 3.9023, df = 9, p-value = 0.003607
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.9
95 percent confidence interval:
2.371053 6.428947
sample estimates:
mean of x
4.4

> [[1]]
> NULL

> [2]]
> NULL

> [[3]]

One Sample t-test

> data:  tab[, i]
> t = -2.6103, df = 9, p-value = 0.02826
> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.9
> 95 percent confidence interval:
> -0.5485048  0.7965048
> sample estimates:
> mean of x
> 0.124

With is output, when I aske for the first or second element from the list like this :

```
h[[1]] 
h[[2]]
```

I get

> NULL
> as result.

What is going wrong in my code?

Comment: `apply(tab, 2, t.test, mu = .9)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial evaluation of the function `t.test` to overwrite default arguments like `mu`:

```r
vec1 <- c(.5,.1, .03, .2, .09, .02,.3,.4,.6,.8)
vec2 <- c(5, 4,3, 8, 3, 1, 4,1, 10, 5)
vec3 <- round(rnorm(10), digits = 2)
tab <- cbind(vec1, vec2, vec3)
tab
#>       vec1 vec2  vec3
#>  [1,] 0.50    5  0.84
#>  [2,] 0.10    4  1.48
#>  [3,] 0.03    3 -0.93
#>  [4,] 0.20    8 -0.43
#>  [5,] 0.09    3 -2.91
#>  [6,] 0.02    1  0.33
#>  [7,] 0.30    4 -0.90
#>  [8,] 0.40    1 -0.20
#>  [9,] 0.60   10  0.75
#> [10,] 0.80    5  0.74

apply(tab, 2, purrr::partial(t.test, mu = 0.9))
#> $vec1
#> 
#>  One Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  newX[, i]
#> t = -7.0941, df = 9, p-value = 5.703e-05
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.9
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.1139489 0.4940511
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x 
#>     0.304 
#> 
#> 
#> $vec2
#> 
#>  One Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  newX[, i]
#> t = 3.9023, df = 9, p-value = 0.003607
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.9
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  2.371053 6.428947
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x 
#>       4.4 
#> 
#> 
#> $vec3
#> 
#>  One Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  newX[, i]
#> t = -2.5636, df = 9, p-value = 0.03051
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.9
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -1.0257116  0.7797116
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x 
#>    -0.123
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>